# Tyre sidewall damage. Safe to drive or replace ASAP?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image][image]
Hey guys. I noticed the above tyre sidewall damage. The tyre is a 245/40R19 Pirelli P Zero, which has a substantial ridge to protect the wheel from damage. The tyre is not losing any pressure over weeks at a time and the tyre ply is not visible.

The tyre has only done 9k miles, and costs £150+, but safety always comes first.

Is it safe to drive until the tread wears out, or should I replace it ASAP? Will it fail UK MOT because of that damage? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say if it will fail the MOT - probably depends on the tester...

But should be fine to continue, do keep an eye on it just in case it starts to separate and bulge.

From the image it just looks to have removed part of the protection ridge.

Comment: I got the car used, with the damage already there. Unfortunately, I noticed the tyre damage a couple of months later when it was too late to call back the dealership. I've driver over 2k miles with it, with no air loss or deformation/bulging. Didn't think much of it, until a friend suggested I might have MOT issues (not due for another year and a half), but I will replace the 4 tyres by then.